# Recursive "Power Of" function

Tags: java, recursion

We are given an assignment to solve a recursive function that can calculate the power of a number using the following rules (took a snapshot):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bphmY.png

I cant seem to figure out to do this as I have been trying for the past 4 hours.
My attempt:

```
public static double power(double x, int n) {   
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    //    x^n = ( x^n/2 )^ 2  if n > 0 and n is even
    if(n % 2 == 0) {
        double value = ((x * power(x, n/2)) * x);
        return value;
    } else {
        double value = x * ((x * power(x, n/2)) * x);
        return value;       
    }
}
```

I believe I am doing wrong when I am multiplying x with the recursive function whereas I should be multiplying by x (power Of = x * x * .... x(n))...

I also can see that in this statement:

```
 double value = ((x * power(x, n/2)) * x);
```

It is wrong because I am not squaring the value but just multiplying it with x. I think I need to store it in a variable first, then do something like value * value to square the end result - but that just gives me a huge number.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this statement:

```
if(n % 2 == 0) {
        double value = ((x * power(x, n/2)) * x);
        return value;
```

It is both syntactically (the brackets don't match) as semantically (deeper recursion, incorrect).

It should be replaced with:

```
if(n % 2 == 0) {
        double value = power(x*x, n/2);
        return value;
```

The reason is that:

> x^(2*k) = (x^2)^k

Which is almost literally what is implemented in the code. Because we know `n` is even, there is a `k = n/2`, such that the above equation holds.

The same with the odd case:

```
else {
        double value = x * power(x*x, n/2);
        return value;
```

This because:

> x^(2*k+1) = x*x^(2*k) (version of @rgettman)

With `k = (n-1)/2`, which can be further optimized to:

> x^(2*k+1) = x*x^(2*k)=x*(x^2)^k (our version)

You can further optimize this as:

```
public static double power(double x, int n) {   
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    double xb = x*x;
    if((n&0x01) == 0x00) {
        return power(xb,n>>>0x01);
    } else {
        return x*power(xb,n>>>0x01);
    }
}
```

Or, you could transform the recursive aspect into a `while` algorithm (since it is mainly *tail-recursion*:

```
public static double power(double x, int n) {
    double s = 1.0d;
    while(n != 0) {
        if((n&0x01) != 0x00) {
            s *= x;
        }
        n >>>= 0x01;
        x *= x;
    }
    return s;
}
```

**Performance**:

three different versions were implemented. This [**jdoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/i6) shows benchmark tests. With:

- `power1` the version of @rgettman;
- `power2` the proposed recursive version in this answer; and
- `power3` the non-recursion version.

In case one sets `L` to `10'000'000` (thus calculating **all** power from `0` up to `L`), one run results in:

```
           L = 10M           L=20M
power1: 1s 630 018 699     3s 276 492 791
power2: 1s 396 461 817     2s 944 427 704
power3: 0s 803 645 986     2s 453 738 241
```

Don't take the numbers after the comma very seriously. Although Java measures in nano-seconds, these numbers are extremely inaccurate and have more to do with side-events (like OS calls, cache-faults,...) than with the real program runtime.

Comment: Not sure which answer I should accept :( P.S - I am having a brain fart. Can you please explain how power(x*x, n/2) works? I don't get the logic how this works even though you're not squaring the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your "even" case, you can calculate it with the recursive call, passing `n/2` as you've done.  But you need to multiply the result with itself to square it.

```
double value = power(x, n/2);
value *= value;
return value;
```

In your "odd" case, you can multiply `x` by the recursive call of the exponent minus `1`.

```
double value = x * (power(x, n - 1));
return value;
```

Comment: It is probably better to perform a division in the odd case as well, since this reduces the number of calls significantly...

Comment: @CommuSoft It may save a call here or there, but when my next recursive call occurs, it will be even, and that will perform a division there too.  So it will happen, even if it's in the next recursive call.

Comment: I think in an average case, the number of calls will be reduced by 25%. And indeed, there is no *extra complexity introduced*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how recursion works internally. Logic is simple is to store the function calls and returned values in a stack. When the method termination condition is reached, pop out the values and return from method.

You need simply this:

```
public static double power(double x, int n) {   
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        double value = (x * power(x, (n-1)));
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: please leave a comment with your negative vote. I want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: @JunedAhson: I didn't downvote, but the problem with this approach is that the algoritm runs in linear time with the power and can (if not optimized), return in a huge stack.

Comment: @CommuSoft Thanks! I tried to present a simple solution and not an optimised solution. This solution is for the questioner and not for the super coders on SO. The question requirement does not talk about complexity of algorithm.

Comment: My dear down voter/ optimised coder. This solution was not for you. Sorry to offend you.